# Martial Law vs Zacama, Primal Calamity

Tags: magic-the-gathering

It's my turn I have priority I control a [Martial Law](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMartial%20Law%5d) ... I detain my opponents [Zacama, Primal Calamity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bZacama%2c%20Primal%20Calamity%5d) ... My spell goes into the stack then I pass priority to my opponent. He uses Zacama's ability to destroy target enchantment in this case my Martial Law. His spell goes into the stack over mine he then passes priority back to me I have nothing else to do and the spells resolves. If both spell resolves this means my enchantments gets destroyed and his Zacama is detained? Or my enchantment survives because he can't active his activated abilities? Sorry still trying to understand the stack! I know his spell resolves first does that means he destroys my enchantment and is not detained?

Comment: I want to point out that there are no spells involved here. You have Martial Law's triggered ability, and Zacama's activated ability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your enchantment will be destroyed, then their creature will be detained.

That happens because, as you guessed, their creature only becomes detained after Martial Law's trigger resolves. Since it's been placed on the stack, and your opponent had priority before it resolved, they can use Zacama's abilities normally. That goes into the stack, and resolves before your triggered ability. Your enchantment will be destroyed, and then its trigger will resolve normally and detain their creature until your next turn.

Comment: I see. Doesn't matter if my "detain target creature" is on top of the stack resolving first? The same thing will happen?

Comment: It doesn't matter, because the *Detain* keyword prevents the creature's abilities from being activated. When they're already on the stack, they've already been activated, so whether the creature is detained or not is not relevant.

Comment: A quick example. I have an Arrest (Same thing as detain but it's an aura spell). I cast Arrest at the beginning of my turn targeting zacama. My opponent has priority he uses zacamas ability destroy target enchantment. When both spell resolves my enchantment gets destroyed? And his zacama is never Arrested? Sorry I just want to make sure been playing magic wrong for sooo long!

Comment: Now that's a different situation. Arrest is a permanent spell, and only becomes a permanent *after* it resolves. If your opponent activates Zacama's ability in response to you casting Arrest, they'll be able to target any artifact or enchantment that's already on the battlefield, but not Arrest, since it hasn't resolved yet. Logically, they won't be able to activate Zacama's ability *after* Arrest resolves.

Comment: @Chris, you seem to be confusing a "stack" with a "queue."  The first thing into a stack, is the last thing to leave a stack.  The last element to enter a stack, is the first thing to leave a stack.  Where as, in a Queue, the first thing to enter a queue, is the first thing to leave a queue.